# How to change image and disable UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a NavigationBar app with two views: a parent and a sub view. In the sub view I'm adding a button to the right corner as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIBarButtonItem *tempButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lock-unlocked.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(lockScreen)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = tempButton;
    [tempButton release];
}
```

When that button is clicked I want to change the image of this rightBarButtonItem and disable the leftBarButtonItem (which was added automatically by the controller). Basically have two states of a button, locked and unlocked.

Question 1:
The only way I can find how to change the image is to create a new UIButtonItem with a new image and replace rightBarButtonItem with that new one. But I'm wondering if there's a way to just change the image without creating a new UIBarButtonItem. Am I creating a memory leak if I keep creating new UIBarButtonItem?

Question 2:
How can I get a hold of self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem and disable/enable it? I don't create that one manually, it's created automatically for me by the controller. I don't see any method/property on UIBarButtonItem to enable/disable user interaction with it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Question 1: Declare UIBarButtonItem *tempButton in the interface

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIBarButtonItem *tempButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *tempButton;
```

and synthesize it in the implementation.

```
@synthesize tempButton;
```

Create the object in viewDidLoad similiar to how you are now.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  tempButtom = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lock-unlocked.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(lockScreen)];
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = tempButton;
}
```

But don't release it here, release it in the dealloc method normally found at the bottom.

Then when lockScreen is called do

```
tempButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]
```

I don't have an answer for question 2, im afraid!

Comment: That approach looks much better. Thanks!

Comment: A tiny issue for the 3rd piece of code: you CAN release tempButton after alloc because it's already been retained when you declare it as a property.

Comment: actually iPhoney. because he did not call self.tempButton, the property will NOT retain. retain property can only be triggered if you use self.VAR

Answer (score 7):

In regard to question 2, use the 'enabled' property:

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 5):

I can't understand if you have a navigationController, but in this case to disable the back button you need to call:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: Won't this hide rather than disable the button?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the above have release the UILabel *l after the [self.window addSubView:l] call? That way it gets retained +1 when added to the Subview, but released -1 in the same branch.  Otherwise, you must call disableLeftBarButtonItemOnNavbar:NO to release it.  And while, you'll end up in the same place in the end, you aren't leaking, I think the static analysis tools they've built into XCode wouldn't like that being in a separate branch.  Small detail :-)

```
- (void) disableLeftBarButtonItemOnNavbar:(BOOL)disable
{
    static UILabel *l = nil;

    if (disable) {
        if (l != nil)
            return;
        l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 160, 44)];
        l.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        l.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.window addSubview:l];
        [l release];
    }
    else {
        if (l == nil)
            return;
        [l removeFromSuperview];
        l = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to disable/grey out a NavBar button with:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

...but hiding the back button works well!

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Thanks Dzamir!

Answer (score 0):

Using "hidesBackButton=YES" is really not an elegant solution, cause it HIDES the button which is not what we want. An acceptable work-around would be adding a UILabel to the window just over the back button at least disabling the touches on the button.

Add this method to your AppDelegate class:

```
- (void) disableLeftBarButtonItemOnNavbar:(BOOL)disable
{
    static UILabel *l = nil;

    if (disable) {
        if (l != nil)
            return;
        l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 160, 44)];
        l.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        l.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.window addSubview:l];
    }
    else {
        if (l == nil)
            return;
        [l removeFromSuperview];
        [l release];
        l = nil;
    }
}
```

You can call it like this from any view controller to disable:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDeleg = (MyAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDeleg disableLeftBarButtonItemOnNavbar:YES];
```

To enable:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDeleg = (MyAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDeleg disableLeftBarButtonItemOnNavbar:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code helps you,

```
UIButton *m_objbtnFlip= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,89, 37)];
    [m_objbtnFlip setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"btn_purchased"
                                                                                                 ofType:IMAGETYPE]]
                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [m_objbtnFlip setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"btn_allavailable"
                                                                                                 ofType:IMAGETYPE]]
                       forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [m_objbtnFlip addTarget:self action:@selector(flipViews) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *objBarButtonItemRight = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:m_objbtnFlip];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=objBarButtonItemRight;
    [objBarButtonItemRight release];
    objBarButtonItemRight = nil;
```

And write action here,

```
-(void)flipViews    {
   // put action code here
}
```